# Get first element of a tuple in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I'm trying to deploy my EKS nodes with only one subnet but I dont know how to give to the resource only one. I show you my code:

```
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "managed_workers" {
  for_each = var.nodegroups[terraform.workspace]

  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.cluster.name
  node_group_name = each.value.Name
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.managed_workers.arn
  subnet_ids      = aws_subnet.private.*.id
```

On the other hand I have a normal task to create the subnets and give the ouput to all my code:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  count = length(local.subnet_priv)
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id[terraform.workspace]
  cidr_block = local.subnet_priv[count.index]
  availability_zone = element(lookup(var.availability_zones, terraform.workspace), count.index)
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
```

So.. I don't know how to get from my subnet_ids argument only the first subnet of the tuple. Now, as you can see, I'm getting all of them but I tried different ways to do but with no success `(aws_subnet.private[0].*.id , aws_subnet.private[0].id, etc)`

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Probably `subnet_ids = [aws_subnet.private[0].id]`.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi you should consider writing that up more fully as an answer because I think that's exactly what the OP was missing. Hache, it can be easier to get an answer if you share the errors (also with the surrounding context) you get from the things that you tried.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR To your recommendation I've added an answer with the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EKS node group `subnet_ids` arguments expects a tuple. In the original example `subnet_ids = aws_subnet.private.*.id` the splat operator is used. The spear operator (`*`) essentially creates a tuple with all the available resources, in our case all the available subnets.

If we want to pass only one subnet from all the available ones, we have to create a tuple with a single element. We could do that by taking the first element from all the existing ones, for example:

```
subnet_ids = [aws_subnet.private[0].id]
```

Although, this might work, I personally don't really consider it to be elegant solution. Certainly a better way to accomplish the same result is to modify the `local.subnet_priv` tuple to contain only one subnet id.

Comment: Nit: the `*` is for [`splat` expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html). The `spread` operator (`...`) on the other hand is for [grouping expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html#grouping-results)

Comment: Corrected, thank you for noticing it.